# parallel read/process/write stop working without any exception

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have to read a file and after processing it's data write result to another file. This process takes too much time so I tried to do read/process/write in a parallel way. Code works well. But there is a problem, when I was testing it for processing very huge file (100GB) after about 40GB program stops working. It do not throw any exception (except 'TimeoutException'). I spend several days and tried to change many things. I know it is not about method or memory. But I am really confused about reason and way to make it works well.

Note: I wanted to post this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but Code Review rules says do not post for trouble shooting and else so I posted it here.

The way I use code (It is on backgroundworker)

```
BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
            ReaderWriterMultiThread readerWriterMultiThread = null;
            int bufferSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
            int readerWriterMultiThreadPartsNumber = 10;
            int sizeToReadInThisIteration = 0;
            int oldprecentage = 0;
            long fileDid = 0;

            using (FileStream streamReader = new FileStream(fromAddress, FileMode.Open))
            using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(streamReader))
            using (FileStream streamWriter = new FileStream(toAddress, FileMode.Open))
            using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(streamWriter))
            {
                sizeToReadInThisIteration = bufferSize * readerWriterMultiThreadPartsNumber;

                streamWriter.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                while (streamWriter.Position < length)
                {
                    if (worker.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }

                    //change sizeToReadInThisIteration if needs
                    if (streamWriter.Position + sizeToReadInThisIteration > length)
                    { sizeToReadInThisIteration = Convert.ToInt32(length - streamWriter.Position); }

                    //new it
                    readerWriterMultiThread = new ReaderWriterMultiThread();

                    //read/do/write
                    readerWriterMultiThread.Start(binaryReader, binaryWriter, bufferSize, sizeToReadInThisIteration,
                        (ref byte[] bytes) => DoNothing(ref bytes));

                    //report process if needs
                    fileDid += sizeToReadInThisIteration;
                    if (((int)(fileDid * 100 / length)) > oldprecentage)
                    {
                        oldprecentage = (int)(fileDid * 100 / length);
                        worker.ReportProgress(oldprecentage);
                    }
                }//while
            }//using
```

`DoNothing` method is:

```
public void DoNothing(ref byte[] bufferToCode)
        {  }
```

and `ReaderWriterMultiThread` class is:( Originally code used threads but I changed it to use tasks.)

```
public class ReaderWriterMultiThread
    {
        #region variables
        //buffer(contain several part)
        List<byte[]> buffer = new List<byte[]>();

        //lock objects
        private object bufferLockForRead = new object();
        private object bufferLockForWrite = new object();

        //indexes
        int readIndex = 0;
        int doReadIndex = 0;
        int doWriteIndex = 0;
        int writeIndex = 0;

        //complete vars
        int lastIndex = int.MaxValue;
        bool readCompleted = false;

        //waiting properties
        private bool doIsWaiting = false;
        private bool writerIsWaiting = false;

        //error properties
        private bool anyErrorHappend = false;
        private string errorsMessage = string.Empty;

        //proc delegate
        public delegate void DelegateMethod(ref byte[] bytes);

        //proc delegate instance
        DelegateMethod delegateM;
        //
        #endregion variables
        //==============================
        #region methods
        //
        public void Start(BinaryReader binaryReader, BinaryWriter binaryWriter, int bufferPartsSize, int size, DelegateMethod delegateMethod)
        {
            //new delegate
            delegateM = new DelegateMethod(delegateMethod);

            //for wait all
            Task[] tasks = new Task[3];

            //run
            var parentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Writer(binaryWriter);
                });

                tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Do();
                });

                tasks[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Reader(binaryReader, bufferPartsSize, size);
                });
            });

            //wait
            parentTask.Wait();
            if (!Task.WaitAll(tasks, 10000))
            { throw new TimeoutException(); }

            if (anyErrorHappend)
            { throw new Exception(errorsMessage); }
        }

        private void AddByReader(byte[] newBytes, bool completed)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (bufferLockForRead)
                {
                    //add data to buffer
                    buffer.Add(newBytes);

                    //updare readIndex
                    readIndex++;

                    //if completed show it
                    if (completed)
                    {
                        readCompleted = true;
                        lastIndex = buffer.Count;//it uses as <lastIndex (so lastIndex = buffer.Count is ok) 
                    }

                    //manage happend error
                    if (anyErrorHappend)
                    {
                        readCompleted = true;
                        lastIndex = doReadIndex + 1;
                    }

                    //if do is waiting pulse it
                    if (doIsWaiting)
                    { Monitor.Pulse(bufferLockForRead); }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString()); }
        }

        private byte[] GetByDo()
        {
            try
            {
                lock (bufferLockForRead)
                {
                    //if data did not read already wait
                    if (doReadIndex == readIndex)
                    {
                        doIsWaiting = true;
                        Monitor.Wait(bufferLockForRead);
                    }

                    //do is not waiting now
                    doIsWaiting = false;

                    //in case of emergency
                    if (doReadIndex > readIndex)
                    { return new byte[0]; }

                    //return
                    return buffer[doReadIndex++];
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString());
                return new byte[0];
            }
        }

        private void AddByDo(byte[] newBytes, string errorMessageFromDO)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (bufferLockForWrite)
                {
                    //add data
                    buffer[doWriteIndex] = newBytes;

                    //update doWriteIndex
                    doWriteIndex++;

                    //error happend in Do
                    if (errorMessageFromDO.Length > 0)
                    {
                        anyErrorHappend = true;
                        errorsMessage += errorMessageFromDO;
                        lastIndex = -1;
                        Monitor.Pulse(bufferLockForWrite);
                    }

                    //if reader completed and writer is in wait state pulse it
                    if (readCompleted && writerIsWaiting)
                    {
                        Monitor.Pulse(bufferLockForWrite);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString()); }
        }

        private byte[] GetByWriter()
        {
            try
            {
                lock (bufferLockForWrite)
                {
                    //if data did not proccessed wait
                    if (writeIndex == doWriteIndex)
                    {
                        writerIsWaiting = true;
                        Monitor.Wait(bufferLockForWrite);
                    }

                    //writer is not waithing
                    writerIsWaiting = false;

                    //return
                    return buffer[writeIndex++];
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString());
                return new byte[0];
            }
        }

        private void Reader(BinaryReader binaryReader, int bufferPartSize, int sizeToRead)
        {
            try
            {
                //vars
                bool completed = false;
                int readedSize = 0;
                byte[] readedBytes = new byte[0];

                while (readedSize < sizeToRead && !anyErrorHappend)
                {
                    //change bufferPartSize & completed if needs
                    if (readedSize + bufferPartSize >= sizeToRead)
                    {
                        bufferPartSize = sizeToRead - readedSize;
                        completed = true;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        //read
                        readedBytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes(bufferPartSize);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString());

                        //error happend
                        anyErrorHappend = true;
                        errorsMessage += ex.Message;

                        //for pulse Do() if it is waiting
                        byte[] amptyBytesArray = new byte[0];
                        AddByReader(amptyBytesArray, true);//it is better to do it instead change lastIndex here

                        break;
                    }

                    //add to buffer
                    AddByReader(readedBytes, completed);

                    //update readedSize
                    readedSize += bufferPartSize;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString()); }
        }

        private void Writer(BinaryWriter binaryWriter)
        {
            try
            {
                //vars
                byte[] bytesToWrite = new byte[0];//for put getted data in

                for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++)
                {
                    //get data from buffer
                    bytesToWrite = GetByWriter();

                    try
                    {
                        //write
                        binaryWriter.Write(bytesToWrite);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString());

                        lastIndex = -1;
                        anyErrorHappend = true;
                        errorsMessage = ex.Message;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString()); }
        }

        private void Do()
        {
            try
            {
                //vars
                byte[] bytes = new byte[0];//for put readed data/result in

                for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++)
                {
                    //get data from buffer
                    bytes = GetByDo();

                    try
                    {
                        //do
                        delegateM(ref bytes);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString());

                        //add
                        AddByDo(new byte[0], "error: " + ex.Message);

                        break;
                    }

                    //add data to buffer
                    AddByDo(bytes, string.Empty);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString());  }
        }
        //
        #endregion methods
    }
```

Comment: Die you attach a debugger when it did hang?

Comment: @Alois Kraus thanks for your response. I run it in debugger and I used try/catch block everywhere so I think if any problem be there it will be catch by them. but I will try way you mentioned and use attaching debugger. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You code is throwing an exception here:

```
 if (!Task.WaitAll(tasks, 10000))
        { throw new TimeoutException(); }
```

Which means that one of your tasks is taking more than 10 seconds to complete.

This could be because it needs more time. It could also be because one of your tasks is getting stuck waiting to enter a lock. It could also because the Monitor.Wait is getting stuck waiting for a lock.

You can add logging to see where it is getting hung. Additionally if one of your assert statements fail it will prevent a task from completing in time.

As a side note, Disk IO is time consuming and in general trying to parallelize IO operations like this typically aren't going to help because the threads end up stomping all over each other contending for disk access time. The disk ends up needing to spin to numerous positions back and forth to read and write data and you end up with a net effect of actually slowing things down. You might be able to speed things up if you are using RAID or you are reading from one disk and adding the reads to a queue and your write thread is reading from that queue and writing that data to a different disk.

Comment: thanks for response. code is not for read/write parallel, it lets process (Do method) run parallel with read and write. Timeoutexception created for avoiding hang and it can not be by deadlock or other reasons you mentioned because it runs this pass many time until reach 40GB and there is no special condition at this point. thank you again.